# Powershell module needed for remove-mfa PS command

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

Which PowerShell module is needed to run the command from the below GitHub sample Individually:

Remove-AzureMFAExpiredBypassUsers

https://github.com/psignoret/ramical-Samples/tree/master/AzureMFAAdminUtils

Answer (score 0):

In the code, you can see the required modules
[image]

The required modules are AzureAD and MSOnline

Hope this helps!